# Background image width

Tags: css, image, dimensions

This is my HTML:

```
<div id="user-avatar"><img src="/imgs/frame.png" alt=""/></div>
```

`user-avatar` class is following:

```
#user-avatar {
     width: 100px;
     height: 100px;
     margin: auto;
     position: relative;
     background: url(images/avatars/128.jpg) 50% 50% no-repeat;
}
```

Frame:

```
#user-avatar img { 
     position: absolute; 
     top: 50%; 
     left: 50%; 
     width: 122px; 
     height: 127px; 
     margin-top: -62px; 
     margin-left: -63px; 
}
```

Original `user-avatar` background image dimensions are 23x25 but I want it to be resized to the 100x100px, and the problem is that whatever I set in the `width: xxx` attribute it'll not work. The avatar that is behind the frame has everytime his original dimensions.

Comment: try this and see if it works width: 100px !important;

Comment: @rs I've tried that already - not worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't resize an image set as background of a container. The only way you can resize a image is using a img tag and resizing it with width and height css attributes.

Take a look [here](http://css-tricks.com/766-how-to-resizeable-background-image/) may be it helps.

Comment: Actually, with CSS3-compliant browsers that support it, you can.

Answer (score 3):

You could use `background-size`, however only the most current browsers support it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/background-size

Answer (score 3):

You can use the CSS3 background-size property, for those browsers that support it, then fall back to a compromise solution for older browsers. The compromise solution could be to set a background color to fill up the space around the background image or to use the background-repeat property to "tile" the image.

For example:

```
#user_avatar {
    ...
    background: url(images/avatars/128.jpg) blue 50% 50% no-repeat;
    background-size: 100px 100px;
}
```

Comment: Well, is there a way to do it in the `img` tag for the best compalibility?

Comment: I suppose you could use two img tags. One, the background, would have src images/avatars/128.jpg and the other, the foreground, have src /imgs/frame.png. You would then use absolute positioning to put the two img tags at the correct location relative to #user-avatar, then set the z-index of the foreground img higher than that of the background img.